# Incompatible types in generic return type method (Java)

Tags: java, generics

New to Java from C++. A method with a generic return type won't compile. I think it's because I'm not specifying the type to the generic method but I don't even know how to do so. The code below does not compile saying: `error: incompatible types: AnInterface cannot be converted to I ... where I is a type-variable:`

To my eyes type `I` sure looks compatible with the return type of `get` since I explicitly declare `I` to be extending `AnInterface`.

```
import java.util.*;

interface AnInterface {
  public int aMethod();
}

class AClass implements AnInterface {
  AClass() { l = new ArrayList<>(); }

  public int aMethod() { return 1; }
  public void add(AnInterface x) { l.add(x); }
  public AnInterface get() { return l.get(0); }

  // method on() will not compile
  public <I extends AnInterface> I on(int x) { I i = get(); return i; }

  List<AnInterface> l;
}

class BClass implements AnInterface {
  public int aMethod() { return 2; }
}

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    AClass a = new AClass(); 
    BClass b = new BClass();
    a.add(b);
    // How do I even call AClass::on()
    // BClass x = a.on<BClass>(); // I expect to call on() like this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a closer look at the method `on`:

```
public <I extends AnInterface> I on() {
    I i = get(); 
    return i; 
}
```

Calling it with `I = BClass` means `get()` must return a `BClass`. But the signature of `get` is `public AnInterface get()`, meaning we just know that it returns an `AnInterface` implementation. It could be a `BClass`, but it could also be anything else implementing `AnInterface`.

You can change `on` like this:

```
public AnInterface I on() {
    AnInterface i = get();
    return i;
}
```

The signature now reveals that `on` returns something implementing `AnInterface`, which is consistent with the type we get back from `get`.

Actually your example already makes clear why the code you posted cannot type check.

```
AClass a = new AClass(); 
AClass b = new AClass();
a.add(b);
BClass c = a.<BClass>on();
```

We expect the call to `on` to return the instance `b`, since this is the first element added to `a`. But `b` is of type `AClass`, not `BClass`. If the compiler would not reject the program, we would have an instance of `AClass` in the variable `c` of type `BClass`.

Comment: `AClass b` was meant to be `BClass b`, I edited my question. I'm understanding why the typecheck fails but in the case where it didn't I still wouldn't know how to call it. `BClass c = a.on<BClass>();` looks like invalid syntax to the compiler.

Comment: It seems to be the other way round, `BClass c = a.<BClass>on()`. I updated this in the answer.